# Hypersurface of contact type

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry, contact-topology

I have the following definitions for a contact structures and hypersurface of contact type in my lecture:

1)A contact structure on a manifold $W^{2n+1}$ is a hyperplane field $\xi \subset TW$ which is maximally non-integrable, meaning that the local defining forms  satisfy 
\begin{align*}
\alpha \wedge d \alpha ^n
\end{align*}
is a local volume form.

An equivalent condition says that for any local defining form $\alpha$, the form $d \alpha$ is symplectic on the fibers of $\xi$.

My first question: Why is this equivalent? $d \alpha$ symplectic form on fibers of $\xi$ means that $(d \alpha)^n$ is a volume form on fibers of $\xi$.

2) $(M, \omega)$ symplectic. A hypersurface $W \subset M$ is called of contact type, if there exists a vector field $Y$ defined on a neighborhood of $W$ in $M$, s.t.

- $Y \pitchfork X$
- $L_Y \omega = \omega$

As a comment, it says that then $W$ is a contact manifold with the contact structure $ker ( \iota_Y \omega)$.

My second question: For this to give a contact structure on $W$, is the first condition necessary?

Answer (score 2):

The first question is just a point-wise issue. If you take a basis $\{v_i\}$ of a fiber of $\xi$, then you can extend it by any tangent vector $v_0$ outside of $\xi$ to a basis of the tangent space in question. Now inserting these vectors into $\alpha\wedge (d\alpha)^n$ the only contribution comes from the term where $v_0$ is inserted into $\alpha$ (since all $v_i$ insert trivially into $\alpha$). But by construction $\alpha(v_0)\neq 0$, so since $(d\alpha)^n$ is a volume form on the fiber of $\xi$, we get a non-zero result.

In the situation of question 2, you first of all need $Y$ to be nowhere vanishing, since otherwise $i_Y\omega$ has zeros. Moreover, you get $d(i_Y\omega)=L_Y\omega=\omega$. If $i_Y\omega$ is a contact form on $W$, then $(i_Y\omega)\wedge\omega^{n-1}$ has to be a volume form on $W$. But $Y$ clearly inserts trivially into that form, so it can't be tangent to $W$ anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't understand the part with $Y$ inserts trivially into that form, since, of course $(i_Y \omega)(Y)=0$ but why is then already $(i_Y \omega) \wedge \omega^{n-1}(Y,....) =0$?

Comment: Up to a multiple, $i_Y\omega^{n-1}$ is just $(i_Y\omega)\wedge\omega^{n-2}$ so in the whole epxression, you get two copies of $i_Y\omega$, whose wedge product is zero.